# How can i get access to a $scope array which is defined in .then() in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my controller code

```
 $http.get(config.url+'/api/employees-suggestion/??token=' + currentUser.token + '&filterEmployee='+ "10000191")
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
       $scope.id_list = [
         {employeeName: 'Hello'},
       ];
       console.log("id_list="+$scope.id_list);
   }, function(response) {
       }
 )
```

i want to get the value of '$scope.id_list' and use it in another an external js file(which is a custom directive for ionic-autocomplete). Here is  directive code,

```
    angular.module('autocomplete.directive', [])

 .directive('ionicAutocomplete',
    function ($ionicPopover) {
      var popoverTemplate = 
       '<ion-popover-view style="margin-top:5px">' + 
         '<ion-content>' +
             '<div class="list">' +
                '<a href="#/tab/badgeboard" class="item" ng-repeat="item in id_list | filter:inputSearch" ng-click="selectItem(item)">{{item.employeeName}}</a>' +
             '</div>' +
         '</ion-content>' +
     '</ion-popover-view>';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            params: '=ionicAutocomplete',
            inputSearch: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var popoverShown = false;
            var popover = null;
            $scope.id_list = $scope.params.id_list;

            //Add autocorrect="off" so the 'change' event is detected when user tap the keyboard
            $element.attr('autocorrect', 'off');


            popover = $ionicPopover.fromTemplate(popoverTemplate, {
                scope: $scope
            });
            $element.on('focus', function (e) {
                if (!popoverShown) {
                    popover.show(e);
                }
            });

            $scope.selectItem = function (item) {
                $element.val(item.display);
                popover.hide();
                $scope.params.onSelect(item);
            };
        }
    };
}
```

);

`{{item.employeeName}}` doesn't print anything in the pop-over as 'id_list' is empty (which is not correct).

if I put following code

```
$scope.id_list = [
    {employeeName: 'Hello'},
     ];
```

outside of .then() everything works correctly `{{item.employeeName}}` prints the employeeName in the pop-over

This is the code in html (view) which is an input field and shows drop-pop-over

```
        <input type="text" ionic-autocomplete="{id_list: id_list, onSelect:onSelect}"placeholder="Search ?" ng-model="search">
```

I tried $rootScope but failed.
What am  I doing wrong? How can i solve this?

Comment: Is your console.log inside then(function(response) getting printed ?

Comment: the second callback function of http.get is for error, have you checked console.log in that function

Comment: Yes it does @NikhileshKV

Comment: try this. define $scope.id_list = [] before your get request and check.

Comment: @NikhileshKV i re-checked but i already did that initialization of id_list=[].

Comment: You're probably having a problem because of limits of scope inheritance. To check this : try $parent.id_list in your HTML template. If it's that. Instead of using `$scope.id_list`, use an intermediary field : `$scope.data = {id_list:[]}`

Comment: @NahiduzzamanRose Can you paste your directive code also. Maybe you are using isolated scope which you shouldn't be using in your case.

Comment: @NikhileshKV i upload it see it

Comment: @Nahiduzzaman Rose check my updated as for ionic-autocomplete answer

Comment: @MohanGopi Thanks sir i'will get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate way of accessing  $scope.id_list in you code you can try this

```
var id_list=[];

 $http.get(config.url+'/api/employees-suggestion/??token=' + currentUser.token + '&filterEmployee='+ "10000191")
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
       id_list = {employeeName: 'Hello'};
      id_list.push({id_list: id_list});
      console.log("id_list="+id_list);
   }, function(response) {
       }
 )
```

here `$scope.id_list.push({id_list: id_list});` will help you to display in UI.

```
 <input type="text" ionic-autocomplete="{id_list: id_list, onSelect:onSelect}"placeholder="Search ?" ng-model="search">
```

and your onSelect

```
$scope.onSelect = function (item) {
        console.log('item', item);

    };
```

this should work fine

Answer (score 2):

A bit of theory:

What `$http.get` returns is called a promise. It is asynchronously resolved (when successful) or rejected (when something goes wrong). If you refer to angular promises documentation, `then()` accepts 2 functions, one for resolve and one for reject.

Usually `$http` calls should take place inside angular services (a "service" or a "factory", these two are very similar). A service like that can be injected into any controller or directive and be reused.

In your case:

There is a good chance that your promise gets rejected, hence what gets executed is the second function you pass to `then()`, and it's currently empty.

Check this one first, and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$scope.$apply()` after you set your result in the callback it will allow angular to see changes made outside of his normal behavior

Comment: Callbacks from promises (such as returned by `$http`) are already handled within the angular digest loop. Don't throw random `$apply()` calls into the code where they aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a service with your `$http.get`

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .service('yourService',['$http', function ($http) {

    this.doMyGet = function ( callbackFunc ) {

      $http.get('YOURURL')
        .success(function (response) {
            callbackFunc(response);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            console.log('error');
        });
    };
}]);
```

Pass the service as a parameter to your controller to use it as shown here:

```
yourService.doMyGet( function (response) {
    $scope.getMyResponse = response;
});
```

Comment: Should i pass it to the directive also?

Comment: It depends. If you want to use the services within the directive, then yes. Otherwise it is not necessary